# Transposing and Expanding Columnar Dataset T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, transpose

I have a SQL table which looks like the following example I whipped up in excel:
[image: sample dataset]

---

The following is my desired result. I need to transform the data above into a 2-column list:

[image: Desired result]

---

Just in case more information is needed, here's that first picture again with notes describing why I used the rows I have:
[image: input table + notes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use Unpivot to get the expected results.

```
create table fruits (fruiteater varchar(100), Fruit1 varchar(100), Fruit2 varchar(100), 
Fruit3 varchar(100), Fruit4 varchar(100), Fruit5 varchar(100), Fruit6 varchar(100))  

insert into fruits values ('Aaron', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple', NULL, NULL, NULL) 
,('Bob', 'Apple', 'Orange', 'Blueberries', 'Peach', 'Mango', 'Banana') 
,('Carter', 'Pear', 'Orange', 'Apple', NULL, NULL, NULL) 
,('David', 'Blueberries', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) 
,('Earnest', 'Mango', 'Orange', 'Pear', 'Apple','Blueberries', NULL) 
,('Frank', 'Raspberries', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)
```

Since all these fruits will be in one column it is very important to take care of data type and length while doing unpivot, so I made sure all the columns are of same data type.

```
select fruiteater, Value as Fruit from fruits
unpivot 
(value for columnname in ([Fruit1], [Fruit2], [Fruit3], [Fruit4], [Fruit5],[Fruit6]))unpvt
```

Output: Unpivot will take care of null values as it eliminates that.

```
fruiteater  Fruit
Aaron   Orange
Aaron   Pear
Aaron   Apple
Bob     Apple
Bob     Orange
Bob     Blueberries
Bob     Peach
Bob     Mango
Bob     Banana
Carter  Pear
Carter  Orange
Carter  Apple
David   Blueberries
Earnest Mango
Earnest Orange
Earnest Pear
Earnest Apple
Earnest Blueberries
Frank   Raspberries
```

Comment: Exceptionally (comprehensive + concise).

Answer (score 2):

UnPivot is certainly more performant, but if you want to dynamically unpivot your data without actually using Dynamic SQL, consider the following

**Example**

```
Select A.fruiteater
      ,C.*
 From  fruits A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item  = a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value = a.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  B.XMLData.nodes('/row')  as C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') as C2(a)
                 Where a.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('fruiteater','OtherColumnsToExclude')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
fruiteater  Item    Value
Aaron       Fruit1  Orange
Aaron       Fruit2  Pear
Aaron       Fruit3  Apple
Bob         Fruit1  Apple
Bob         Fruit2  Orange
Bob         Fruit3  Blueberries
Bob         Fruit4  Peach
Bob         Fruit5  Mango
Bob         Fruit6  Banana
Carter      Fruit1  Pear
Carter      Fruit2  Orange
Carter      Fruit3  Apple
David       Fruit1  Blueberries
Earnest     Fruit1  Mango
Earnest     Fruit2  Orange
Earnest     Fruit3  Pear
Earnest     Fruit4  Apple
Earnest     Fruit5  Blueberries
Frank       Fruit1  Raspberries
```

Comment: Wow there is a lot in here I haven't been exposed to yet. The following line contains most of what I haven't seen: `Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)`. Can you explain what's going on in this line? Specifically  RE: `values`, `for`, `XML RAW`, & `Foo(XMLData)`

Comment: @RobTruxal Cross Apply B will convert the record into XML. and Cross Apply C will Unpivot the data.   I was a slow adopter of XML.  It may be worth your time to add another arrow to your quiver.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti . . . I think XML may be overkill in this case.  For an `unpivot`, the columns are well defined, because the table is well defined.  The power of XML is really for the `pivot`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff No argument from me.  I simply noticed the "aka Fruit n" in the image which lead me to believe variable columns.

Answer (score 1):

I much prefer lateral joins (`apply`) for this purpose.  I think the syntax is simpler and it doesn't do anything "magic" like remove `NULL` values unless you explicitly want it to:

```
select f.fruiteater, v.fruit
from fruits f cross apply
     (values (fruit1),  (fruit2),  (fruit3), (fruit4), (fruit5), (fruit6)
     ) v(fruit)
where v.fruit is not null;
```

More importantly, `unpivot` is very specific syntax for one purpose.  Lateral joins are very flexible and powerful.  Using them for unpivoting is a pretty simply way to learn about them.